# Reactive Extension on method called by property

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive

I never worked with the ReactiveExtensions before. I looked online and couldnt really find a way fitting my needs. All examples seems a bit "overdone" comparing to what I need to achieve.

I have a method that does everything for me, so I dont need to return the values and then set my list. All I want is to execute the method when the user stops typing eventually and not whilst the user is typing. How can I achieve this by using reactive extensions.

Currently I have the following:

```
private string _searchText;
public String SearchText
{
  get { return _searchText; }
  set
  {
    _searchText = value;
    MyMethod();   
  }
}

<textbox Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your properties shold not do other than set the value on the backing field and raise change notifications.** **EVERY other logic should be put outside**, listening to those change notifications through an Observable.

In your case, you want to listen to the notifications only after a certain amount of time is passed, so you can use the [IObservable.Throttle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229400) operator to wait a certain time interval before forwarding the notification.

So, this can be a simple implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

This is how you should write EVERY property:

```
// Just check if value is different from the actual backing field.
// If and only if it is, set the backing field and raise the PropertyChanged event.
public string SearchText
{
    get { return _SearchText; }
    set
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(_SearchText, value))
        {
            _SearchText = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
private string _SearchText;
```

**FIRST SOLUTION: Throttle in the ViewModel:**

```
// Transform the PropertyChanged event in an Observable
var changed = Observable.FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
    h => PropertyChanged += h,
    h => PropertyChanged -= h);

// Transform the Observable to your need,
// filtering only when SearchText changes
changed.Where(x => x.EventArgs.PropertyName == nameof(SearchText))
// Wait 500 ms before forwarding the notification;
// if another char in inserted from the user beside this interval,
// the previous value is ignored
.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500))
// Necessary to avoid cross-thread Exceptions
.ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)
// finally, subscribe your method:
.Subscribe(_ => MyMethod());
```

You can put the above code wherever is opportune: in the constructor of the ViewModel, in a `Init()` method...

**SECOND SOLUTION: Use the Delay property of the Bindings**

```
Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Delay=500}"
```

It has the same result.